# ¿Cómo puede cambiar el idioma con que se corre Pandoc para generar PDFs utilizando markdown?

Tags: latex, atom-editor, markdown, yaml

Últimamente he estado utilizando Atom como editor de texto para escribir reportes, trabajos y demás. Pero no encuentro la manera de que mi trabajo en markdown se exporte a un PDF tipo LaTeX con índices y notas en **español**. Es decir, que diga "Figura 1" en vez de "Figure 1" o "Resumen" en lugar de "Abstract". Trabajando normalmente con LaTeX eso se haría con "\usepackage[spanish]{babel}", pero no sé como hacer lo mismo en un archivo markdown. Supongo que habrá alguna opción para utilizar en el YAML front matter y que Pandoc pueda hacer el trabajo. ¿Alguien sabe como hacerlo? Gracias :)

Answer (score 1):

Ok. Encontré algo en la documentación de Pandoc. En "Language variables" menciona que se puede utilizar la variable "lang" en el YAML Front Matter para cambiar como será compilado el documento LaTeX vía Pandoc. Para configurar el idioma se utilizan los tags del IETF language.
Aquí algunos:

- French:   fr
- German:   de
- Polish:   pl
- Dutch:    nl
- Finnish: fi
- Swedish: sv
- Italian:  it
- Spanish (Spain):  es
- Portuguese (Portugal):    pt
- Russian:  ru
- Portuguese (Brazil):  pt-BR
- Spanish (Mexico): es-MX
- Chinese (PRC):    zh-CN
- Chinese (Taiwan): zh-TW
- Japanese: ja
- Korean:   ko

https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#language-variables
https://gist.github.com/traysr/2001377